# Tab Bar buttons and toolbar button on ipad not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, toolbar

I have an app that has been working on the iphone with no problems.  I need to compile and test so it will run on the ipad.  I've changed the Project Deployment option, Targeted Device Family, to iphone/ipad.  I've installed it and run it on an iPhone with no problems after making this change.

When I run/debug using the ipad simulator or ipad device several controls no longer function.
The main view controller has a tab bar controller.  Pressing the buttons on the tab bar doesn't open the view controllers.

On the main view I can also open a different view by pressing a button (not a tab bar button).
Pressing the button does open the second view.  On the second view there is a navigation bar with a bar button item.  That bar button item isn't functioning either.  Pressing it doesn't open the expected view.

The iOS deployment target is set to iOS 4.2.
Are there other options I should set to enable the app for iPad?  Are there coding changes required for the tab controller to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found literally no resources to help resolve the issue.   However, after some fiddling, I realized that touch events were not getting sent to anything in the lower portion of the screen.  This suggests that the UIWindow is not covering the entire screen of the iPad (although the subviews appear to get drawn correctly).  There should be an option in builder to make the window full screen on load.  If this doesn't work try using a separate .xib file for the iPad and set the window size properly.  This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a solution.  I opened the original project.
Under the Projects Menu there is a submenu for Upgrade Current Project for iPad.
That fixed the issue for me.  I originally made a couple of changes to the code
before I did this.  I had to go back to the original project source and then
apply the submenu upgrade to ipad option before the app would work correctly.